# Cant pull text out of tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

this works...

```
    print soup.findAll('td',{ "class" : "green center" })
```

but I only need the text and this wont work...

```
    print soup.findAll('td',{ "class" : "green center" }).text
```

here is how im using it.

```
#!python27
import fileinput
import sys
import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re, urllib
filename = "url.txt"
LineNumber=0
f=open(filename)
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
        filehandle = urllib.urlopen("http://kat.ph/usearch/"+lines[LineNumber]+"/")
        line = filehandle.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        print soup.findAll('td',{ "class" : "green center" }).text
        print soup.findAll('td',{ "class" : "red lasttd center" }).text
        print LineNumber
        LineNumber=LineNumber+1

        filehandle.close()
```

Post script url.txt is just a list of searches to be ran.

Comment: Have you looked at the error message? (`ResultSet` has no attribute `text`) That should have given you a clue =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll` returns a list of all elements that meet your criteria `"class":"green center"`, etc. If you're interested in returning a single element of that list, you can call it by offset:

```
print soup.findAll('td',{'class':'green center'})[0].text
print soup.findAll('td',{'class':'green center'})[1].text
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over the list:

```
for td in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'green center'}):
    print td.text
```

Further, if you were interested in combining all of the text within the list, you could append each element to a list and join:

```
td_list = []
for td in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'green center'}):
    td_list.append(td.text)
print ' '.join(str(x) for x in td_list)
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

`findAll` will get a list of elements, you need to loop through the list and call `.text` on each element.

```
for e in soup.findAll('td',{ "class" : "green center" }):
    print e.text
```